# validate if statement after initial validation at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an if statement to do .load() of elements if two conditions are met:

```
if (current_items <= {{total_hits}} && infinite_scroll != 'disabled') {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
            var sort_by = $('#sort_by').val();

                if ($('input:checkbox:checked').val()) {
                    var category_filter = ""
                    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                           category_filter += "\""+$(this).val()+"\","
                         });
                    category_filter = category_filter.substring(0, category_filter.length - 1);
                }else{
                    var category_filter = "all"
                }
            $.get('/search_ajax/{{query}}/'+sort_by+'/'+current_items+'/'+category_filter, function(data){
              $(data).appendTo("#container");
              current_items = $('[class="small-3 columns"]').length;
            });
        }
    });
  }
```

It's working fine for the first condition but now I want to disable/enable it based on the second condition, the variable infinite_scroll.
This variable is "enabled" or "disabled" at load time and works fine then.
The problem is that when I change the value with another jquery call, it does not work.
I guess the if is checked once when it loads and it's not evaluated again, and that's why it doesn't work.
The variable does change value after using the jquery call.

Any ideas on how to see what's wrong or use another approach?

Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `if` statements doesn't automatically get re-evaluated after page load, but you can do it by including the above code in a function and calling it each time after you change the `infinite_scroll` variable, here's the solution:

```
function changeSroll(current_items, infinite_scroll) {
  if (current_items <= {{total_hits}} && infinite_scroll != 'disabled') {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
          if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
              var sort_by = $('#sort_by').val();

                  if ($('input:checkbox:checked').val()) {
                      var category_filter = ""
                      $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                             category_filter += "\""+$(this).val()+"\","
                           });
                      category_filter = category_filter.substring(0, category_filter.length - 1);
                  }else{
                      var category_filter = "all"
                  }
              $.get('/search_ajax/{{query}}/'+sort_by+'/'+current_items+'/'+category_filter, function(data){
                $(data).appendTo("#container");
                current_items = $('[class="small-3 columns"]').length;
              });
          }
      });
    }
}
```

Now, each time where you change the `infinite_scroll` variable, add this line:

```
changeSroll(current_items, infinite_scroll);
```

Hope this does what you're trying to do.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much :-), will accept as answer as soon as the system lets me